AUGraph kAudioUnitProperty_SetRenderCallback callback not invoke probabilistically
my auGraph struct is below. It use for record and play.
RenderCallback -> C16i_32fConvert -> timePitch  -> C32f_16iConvert -> ioUnit -> RecordCallback

EveryTime I startRecord And Play, I AUGraphAddNode、AUGraphOpen、AudioUnitSetProperty、set kAudioUnitProperty_SetRenderCallback & kAudioOutputUnitProperty_SetInputCallback、AUGraphInitialize、AUGraphStart
EveryTime I stopRecord And Play, I AUGraphStop、AUGraphUninitialize、AUGraphClose、DisposeAUGraph
In iphone 8 plus, I found that when I repeat 'StartRecord And Play' &  'StopRecord And Play' several times. The RenderCallback not invoke. (RecordCallback invoke correctly).
Why? Am I recreating and releasing too many times？

I simplified the structure of the AuGraph to just one ioUnit. There doesn't seem to be an issue where you only trigger the RecordCallback but not the RenderCallback

I found a lame solution. I set a timer for 100ms after AUGraphStart. If RenderCallback is not triggered within 100ms, call AUGraphStop -> AUGraphStart once. As a result, you repeat this process about twice, and the RenderCallback and the RecordCallback are normal. Does anyone know why this method works, and the cause of this problem.

Dammit, the above method of setting the timer to restart AuGraph sometimes fails. There's a chance it won't work no matter how many times it's restarted. Do you have a better solution

My guess is that the speaker resources are occupied. Before using AuGraph for playback and recording. The audio is played using an AudioQueue in the project code, which calls the stop operation but does not release resources.
